# Listing Outlook emails by specific range hour

Tags: sql, email, time, filter, outlook

I am trying to list all the emails that have been sent between 5PM and 6PM with the Advanced Search of Outlook but I am facing a problem. As far as I see, there is possibility to use the SQL search, but I cannot make it work. It would look like this:

`"urn:schemas:httpmail:timesent" > '17:00' AND "urn:schemas:httpmail:timesent" < '18:00'`

Thanks.

Comment: What does the `timesent` field actually store?  Can you include sample data for that?

Comment: `timesent` would actually correspond to the time an email has been sent out (this keyword does not exist, this is just an example of what I want to achieve with an SQL query). In the blogs, I only found the keyword `datereceived`, but I am not interested in this one. Other solutions would consist in querying the Outlook DB directly via VB/VBA/... and filter by time but I would prefer avoiding this solution.

Comment: You didn't fully answer my question.  We need to see the format of `timesent`.  Are you sure it is only a time component, and no date?  I would think the time sent would also have a date, since, after all, it happened on some date.

Comment: This would be similar to `datereceived` (e.g., "01.06.2017 12:00 AM").

Comment: Here is a [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/cc513841(v=office.12)#SearchingOutlookData_Date-TimeComparisons) link.  I'm not sure it's possible to do what you have in mind, as the flavor of SQL being used is fairly primitive.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include just the time portion. You need to include both date *and* time.

```
urn:schemas:httpmail:timesent" > '10-22-2018 17:00' AND "urn:schemas:httpmail:timesent" < '10-22-2018 18:00'
```